# Method that checks the result of another method for an if statement

Tags: java

I need to alter a method in a class:

```
public void removeFile(int index) {
    if(index >= 0 && index < files.size()) {
        files.remove(index);
    }
}
```

to use this method:

```
public boolean validIndex(int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index > files.size() - 1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;

    }
}
```

instead of this part of the first method:

```
if(index >= 0 && index < files.size())
```

The aim is that the first method checks whether the second method returns as true before it removes the file.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: if the methods are in the same class, just use `if(validIndex(index))`

Comment: As a side-note, you can just `return index >= 0 && index < files.size()` in the `validIndex` method.

Comment: thanks guys    this: if(validIndex(index)) sorted it. Any explanation as to why that works?

Comment: Because the if statement evaluates true or false statements and your validIndex function returns a boolean i.e. (true or false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?:

```
public void removeFile(int index)
    {
        if(validIndex(index))
        {
            files.remove(index);
        }

    }




   public boolean validIndex(int index)
   {
       return (index >= 0 && index < files.size() - 1);
   }
```

Comment: It should be `index < files.size()` (not - 1).